# QStyledItemDelegate::paint - Why is my text not properly aligned?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm giving Qt a go and want have a model display in a custom text color based on its value.  It's an optional setting to render it in color, so I'd like to avoid using Qt::ForegroundRole in my model and instead implement this in a QStyledItemDelegate.  In the following sample, I call `QStyledDelegate::paint` and then proceed to draw an additional copy of the same text in red using `painter->drawText`.  My expectation is that they should overlay perfectly, whereas in reality there appears to be an margin around the text when using `QStyledDelete::paint`.

Here's a link to a picture which better shows what I am talking about:

[image]

Now for some relevant source code.
`mainwindow.cpp` contains:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->treeView->setItemDelegate(new TestDelegate());

    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
    ui->treeView->setModel(model);

    QList<QStandardItem*> items;
    items << new QStandardItem("Moose")
          << new QStandardItem("Goat")
          << new QStandardItem("Llama");

    model->appendRow(items);
}
```

`testdelegate.cpp` contains:

```
void TestDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    if (index.data().toString() == "Goat") {
        painter->save();
        painter->setPen(Qt::red);
        painter->drawText(option.rect, option.displayAlignment, index.data().toString());
        painter->restore();
    }
}
```

This aforementioned behavior occurs under both my Windows 7 and Linux Mint test boxes running Qt 4.8.x.  The text margin under both systems appears to be x+3, y+1; yet I fear this may be font-dependent and do not wish to hard code offsets that could potentially break things.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`option.rect` is the bounding rectangle of the item view cell, as such it contains no margin.  The offset you require can be retrieved by querying the sub-element rectangle from the current `QStyle`:

```
...
QStyle* style = QApplication::style();
QRect textRect = style->subElementRect(QStyle::SE_ItemViewItemText, &option);
...
painter->drawText(textRect, option.displayAlignment, index.data().toString());
```

*However*...  It is entirely up to the current `QStyle` whether it implements it or not.  When I tried using it with Qt v4.8 for my application on Linux/Gnome, it was wrong, and indeed not implemented in the Qt source code.  So I had to hard code the offset, for me that wasn't so bad as I intend on writing my own `QStyle` - you may not be as 'lucky'.

Comment: After a bit of playing around, I've gotten this to work using the following:  

`QStyleOptionViewItemV4 opt = option;  
initStyleOption(&opt, index);  
opt.palette.setBrush(QPalette::Text, QBrush(Qt::red));  
QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &opt, painter);`  


Instead of `QApplication::syle()`, `opt.widget->style()` can also be used to prevent a QApplication include.  (Apologies for failing at formatting this comment.)

Comment: This isn't the same thing.  You asked about drawing text where an item view item _would_ draw it, whereas you have simply drawn an item view item with coloured elements (something that can be done from the model using the appropriate colour roles - no custom delegate required).