# Python QStyledItemDelegate - How do I properly align the text

Tags: python, pyside6

This question is almost identical to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778029/qstyleditemdelegatepaint-why-is-my-text-not-properly-aligned) question. However, the solution did not work for me and the question is an older version of Qt. I am using a `QStyledItemDelegate` to color certain cells based on their value. However, after these cells are colored, the text in them shifts far to the upper left. Using Alignment flags helps the issue but they are still far to the left (maybe only a space or two). In the code below, a table is created and the columns next to `GOAT` are highlighted to demonstrate this. We can see the text is 'more' to the left than the other cells. How do I fix this? `translate` moves the whole cell, not just the text. Is there a way to just move the text?

```
import sys

import pandas as pd
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QPen, QBrush, QColor
from PySide6.QtWidgets import  QStyledItemDelegate


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._dfDisplay = data
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data[index.column()][index.row()]
            return str(value)

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Orientation.Horizontal:
            if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._dfDisplay.columns[col])
        return None


class MyDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        super().paint(painter, option, index)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.GlobalColor.black, 3))

        # Highlight our bm and tbm ROE cells
        if index.siblingAtColumn(0).data() in ["GOAT"]:
            if index.column() > 0:
                # Set the fill color
                brush = QBrush(QColor('#90EE90'))
                brush.setStyle(Qt.SolidPattern)
                painter.setBrush(brush)
                # Set the outline color
                painter.setPen(Qt.GlobalColor.white)
                painter.drawRect(option.rect)
                # Draw the text
                painter.setPen(Qt.GlobalColor.black)
                painter.translate(1, 0)
                painter.drawText(option.rect,Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignVCenter, str(index.data()))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.delegate = MyDelegate()
        self.table.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)

        header_view = CustomHeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Horizontal)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeader(header_view)
        data = pd.DataFrame([["GOAT", "Giraffe", "Potatoe", "Another"],
                             [77, 33, 111111, 233],
                             [50, 70, 89, 100000]
                             ])
        print(data)

        self.model = TableModel(data)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Why don't you just add support for `BackgroundRole` and `ForegroundRole` to your model? If the `index` is at column > 0 and the value of first column is a match, return those colors.

Comment: Unless you're replying to somebody else, please don't use comments to expand the question, [edit] it instead!

Comment: At first, the table was not respecting my `BackgroundRole`s but now it is. Odd, maybe I had it in `headerData` or something. Thanks for the reminder, good to go!

Comment: In any case, if you only need to change the text and background color in the delegate, you should not try to override `paint()` (unless you *really* know what you're doing and how style painting works). A more simple and appropriate solution is to *only* override `initStyleOption()` of QStyledItemDelegate and eventually set the `opt.backgroundBrush = QBrush(QColor('#90EE90'))` and set the palette color of the `Text` role: `opt.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor(Qt.white))`. Check the documentation about QStyleOptionViewItem and QPalette.

Comment: Also: 1. use imports more consistently (sometimes you use the submodule, other times the classes, but you should try to decide which one of them you want to use and stick with it); 2. you are also mixing usage of enum names, which may make code editing and debugging difficult; sometimes you use the enum namespace, others the class: eg. `Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole` and `Qt.DisplayRole`; you should use the first mode since Qt6; 3. **always** check the examples you provide: your code is not reproducible unless further editing is done on our part, and we should really not be distracted by that.

Comment: 100%, I try to always be as specific as possible with my imports. My IDE always wants to use less specific imports. It is frustrating!

Comment: The problem is not specificity, but consistency. For instance, QStyledItemDelegate is imported from QtWidgets, but you are already importing that module. So, you either use the `QtWidgets` prefix for anything (including QStyledItemDelegate), or you eventually import individual classes from the submodules. Qt is quite verbose in its naming (and enums make it even worse), so I normally avoid the modules namespaces. If you know what you're doing, you can even just do wildcard imports from each submodule: while it's normally discouraged, it's not forbidden per se, and may make things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is mostly conceptual.

If you just want to alter the background and foreground color of an item, overriding the `paint()` function of an item delegate is usually not the correct choice.

If the appearance has to be consistent from the model part and within *all* its connected views, then you must properly implement the `data()` function of the model:

```py
class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    ...
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return
        elif role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data[index.column()][index.row()]
            return str(value)
        elif (
            role in (Qt.BackgroundRole, Qt.ForegroundRole)
            and index.column() > 0
        ):
            leftValue = self._data[0][index.row()]
            if leftValue == 'GOAT':
                if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
                    return QColor('#90EE90')
                else:
                    return QColor(Qt.white)
```

If you don't want to alter the behavior of the model and only change the appearance in specific views, then, again, don't try to alter the painting, but just rely on the [`initStyleOption()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstyleditemdelegate.html#initStyleOption) of the delegate:

```py
class MyDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, opt, index):
        super().initStyleOption(opt, index)
        if index.column() and index.siblingAtColumn(0).data() == 'GOAT':
            opt.backgroundBrush = QBrush(QColor('#90EE90'))
            opt.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor(Qt.white))
```

The above approach is not only more accurate, but also *safer*.

The `paint()` function of an item delegate strongly relies on the current QStyle implementation, which internally uses QStyle functions to compute appropriate margins and spacings within each item.

Each QStyle accesses its internal functions in different ways, most of the times by calling those functions internally, so there is absolutely no certain way to know where the internal objects of an item will be finally shown. Some styles use public functions that can be overridden, but others do that privately, and while there are some "safer" ways to draw item objects that normally work in most circumstances, trying to manually do that drawing is, most of the times, a "leap of faith".

Considering the above, your attempt in overriding `paint()` has a lot of issues:

- if you want to customize background and foreground painting, you shall not call the base implementation;
- you're setting a pen even before checking if the custom painting has to be done or not;
- the default brush style is always `SolidPattern`, so there's no point in redundantly setting it;
- translating a *received* painter that is probably be furtherly used for other aspects (eg: other items!) is *wrong*, since it may translate every further painting that happens after it; the `save()` and `restore()` functions should be used instead, before and after applying such important changes to the painting context;

At the very least, a proper delegate `paint()` function that alters the default behavior should do the following:

1. create a *clone* of the given option;
2. call `initStyleOption()` with that option and the given index;
3. get the current style (either from the `option.widget` or the QApplication instance);
4. store the current option's data that needs custom painting and overwrite it with empty/invalid data;
5. change the basic options that need to be overridden (such as the background);
6. use the given style to draw the primitive `PE_PanelItemViewItem`;
7. use QStyle options to get further aspects of the item (checkbox and/or decoration geometries, available text rect, current item state, etc.) also based on the original option;
8. use QStyle functions to draw *over* what's necessary, eventually considering QFontMetrics aspects proper text displaying, including elision;

I understand that the above may seem a big complication, but that's how Qt allows complex drawing of items in views, and if you need deeply custom behavior you **must** follow those aspects if you want to provide a look that is as close as possible to the default behavior.

I strongly suggest you to **never** underestimate all these aspects: even if you end up never using them, being aware of them is quite mandatory. So, take your time to review the *whole* documentation about:

- QStyle;
- QStyleOption (and **all** inherited classes);
- QPainter and related classes such as QPen, QBrush, QColor and QPalette;
- QAbstractItemView, QAbstractItemModel and the [Qt model/view programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html) guides in general;
- QAbstractItemDelegate and related classes;
- QFontMetrics;
- all geometry based classes that are related to painting in some way, such as QPoint, QLine, QRect, QPolygon (and their floating point counterparts), but also QPainterPath and QRegion;